# Perform a 'join' on two numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, data-manipulation

I have two numpy array's that look like the following:

```
a = np.array([[1, 10], [2, 12], [3, 5]])
b = np.array([[1, 0.78], [3, 0.23]])
```

The first number in the list is the id parameter, and the second one is a value. I'm looking to combine them. The expected output to be equal to this:

```
np.array([1, 10, 0.78], [2, 12, 0], [3, 5, 0.23])
```

Is there a function (or combination of functions that can do this for me? Any help is greatly appreciated.

If an object is not found, a 0 is put in it's place.

Comment: I don't follow the logic of the expected output: how is `[2, 12, 0]` derived from the entries of  `a` and `b`? Based on my interpretation of your description, I would've expected the output to be `np.array([1, 10, 0.78], [2, 12], [3, 5, 0.23])` or `np.array([1, 10, 0.78], [2, 12, 0], [3, 5, 0.23])` (the latter if a value `0` means "not found in that array").

Comment: NumPy arrays are not designed for jagged structures like what you appear to want. It is possible to create arrays of arrays or arrays of lists to represent jagged arrays, but they'll be incompatible with most NumPy operations and have all sorts of nasty edge cases, too.

Comment: My apologies, this has been updated. The goal is not to create a jagged array, but represent two lists of data that need to be combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the the first element like a `key` of a dictionary or an index of a Pandas series.  So I used those tools which are better suited for the combination you are looking to do.  I then convert back to the array you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 10], [2, 12], [3, 5]])
b = np.array([[1, 0.78], [3, 0.23]])

pd.concat(
    map(pd.Series, map(dict, (a, b))), axis=1
).fillna(0).reset_index().values

array([[ 1.  , 10.  ,  0.78],
       [ 2.  , 12.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 3.  ,  5.  ,  0.23]])
```

Notes:

1. I map `dict` and `pd.Series` on the iterable `(a, b)`
2. I pass those to `pd.concat` which produces a Pandas DataFrame
3. Fill in missing values with `0`
4. Reset the index to get back those keys of yours
5. Get at just the values

---

If you have another array

```
a = np.array([[1, 10], [2, 12], [3, 5]])
b = np.array([[1, 0.78], [3, 0.23]])
c = np.array([[1, 3.14], [2, 3.14]])

pd.concat(
    map(pd.Series, map(dict, (a, b, c))), axis=1
).fillna(0).reset_index().values

array([[ 1.  , 10.  ,  0.78,  3.14],
       [ 2.  , 12.  ,  0.  ,  3.14],
       [ 3.  ,  5.  ,  0.23,  0.  ]])
```

---

If you want to quickly convert you arrays to the Pandas series
Notice that I wrote to new names `a_`, `b_`, and `c_` to avoid overwriting your other names

```
a_, b_, c_ = map(pd.Series, map(dict, (a, b, c)))
```

---

To get a DataFrame

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.Series, map(dict, (a, b, c))), axis=1).fillna(0)
df

    0     1     2
1  10  0.78  3.14
2  12  0.00  3.14
3   5  0.23  0.00
```

Comment: Ok, this helps. So if I'm working on a project where I have a lot of keys and values, it seems like pandas would be the way to go.

Comment: The answer above makes sense, but I need to be able to expand it. For example, if I have c = np.array([[1, 3.14], [2, 3.14]]), how can I add that to the array, creating [[1, 10, 0.78, 3.14], [2, 12, 0, 3.14], [3, 5, 0.23, 0]]

Comment: And if something like that is easier to do in pandas, I'm happy to use that tool instead.

Comment: Glad I could help.